# What is the use of the "/" character in boost::filesystem::path?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I ran across this line in a C++ program and don't understand how or why the "/" is used.  Any suggestions?

boost::filesystem::path pathLockFile = GetDataDir() / ".lock";

Comment: Operator overload? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: `GetDataDir` does not sound like a function in Boost -- it does not follow their naming convention. Which one of your libraries defines that function?

Comment: You have all the source code, why don't you read it or step through it in a debugger? Also, concerning just the topic of your question, consider `a = b / c;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple case of operator overloading.
The `operator/` has been overloaded for the objects of type `path`.
When you use `/` on `boost::filesystem::path` objects, it appends them.

So when you write :
`boost::filesystem::path pathLockFile = GetDataDir() / ".lock";`

It expands to something like:
`boost::filesystem::path pathLockFile = boost::filesystem::path("/tmp/data") / ".lock";`

Assuming that `GetDataDir()` is returning `/tmp/data` as a `boost::filesystem::path`, in *Unix/Linux* like environment. In windows-like system, the answer would differ.

This further expands to :
`boost::filesystem::path pathLockFile = boost::filesystem::path("/tmp/data") / boost::filesystem::path(".lock");`

And finally you get `pathLockFile` is holding the value `/tmp/data/.lock`

---

Read the docs from [Boost Filesystem and Path](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-concatenation)

> path operator/ (const path& lhs, const path& rhs);
>   Returns: path(lhs) /= rhs.

*path appends*
The append operations use operator/= to denote their semantic effect of appending the platform's preferred directory separator when needed.
The preferred directory separator is implementation-defined.

**/** (forward slash) separator => for unix variants, Linux, and Mac OS X
**\** (back slash) separator => for windows-like implementations

> path& operator/=(const path& p);
>   Returns: *this

Comment: Are `operator/` and `operator/=` equivalent and interchangeable?

Comment: @Åsmund 
From the boost [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html)
`path operator/ (const path& lhs, const path& rhs);`
`Returns: path(lhs) /= rhs.`
So `/` uses `/=` internally. The difference is that `/` returns a new `path` object whereas `/=` does not return a new object. So they are not interchangeable in that sense.